How should I do data gathering for EU Traffic LAWS?
I am trying to do a project for which I need a huge corpus on EU TRAFFIC LAW specifically speed limit, signage, general regulations, offenses, penalties. I did find the resources like Eur-lex, european commision etc but I am having a hard time collecting data manually. Can someone suggest or help me in automating this process or maybe tell me some resources where I can get this data more easily.
